# Unable to locate a P element with Cucumber

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, watir

i am using Cucumber to test a website, i would like to click on the login icon, but i got the following error :

```
@b.p(text:"Se connecter").click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Paragraph: located: true; {:text=>"Se connecter", :tag_name=>"p"}> to be present
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/watir-6.12.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:627:in `raise_present'
```

here are my test :

```
@b.p(text:"Se connecter").visible?
2019-04-02 15:42:30 WARN Watir ["visible_element"] #visible? behavior will be changing slightly, consider switching to #present? (more details: http://watir.com/element-existentialism/)
=> false
```

But i do see the text on the page.

```
pry(#<Object>)> @b.p(text:"Se connecter").exist?
=> true

pry(#<Object>)> @b.p(text:"Se connecter").enabled?
=> true
```

i also tried to click on other element but it doesn't work either.

Thanks for Helping

Comment: It would help if you can provide the HTML or a page that reproduces the issue. The error message says the element is found, but not visible to the user. Are you sure you are clicking on the right element - usually I would expect a button or link element. The other possibility is there are multiple on the page, so you could try `@b.p(text: "Se connecter", visible: true).click`

Comment: Thanks for your help Justin, @b.p(text: "Se connecter", visible: true).click works :)